# Vuetify reset form after submitting

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using a form inside dialog using vuetify.
Imported the component in page like this -

```
<template>
  <div>
    <topicForm :dataRow="dataRow" v-model="dialog" />
  </div>
</template>

methods: {
      openDialog(item = {}) {
      this.dataRow = item;
      this.dialog = true;
      },
}
```

Dialog form code -->

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-dialog v-model="value" max-width="500px" @click:outside="close">
      <v-card outlined class="pt-5">
        <v-form ref="form" class="px-3">
          <v-card-text class="pt-5">
            <v-row no-gutters>
              <v-text-field
                required
                outlined
                label=" Name"
                v-model="data.name"
                :rules="[rules.required]"
              ></v-text-field>
            </v-row>
            <v-row no-gutters>
              <v-textarea
                required
                outlined
                label=" Description"
                v-model="data.description"
              ></v-textarea>
            </v-row>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-form>
        <v-divider> </v-divider>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn
            large
            dark
            outlined
            color="success"
            @click="save"
            class="ma-3"
          >
            Save
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </div>
</template>

  props: [
    "dataRow",
    "value",
    // ----------------------
  ],

methods: {
    save() {
      if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
        this.$root
          .$confirm("Are you sure you want to save?")
          .then((confirm) => {
            if (confirm) {
              this.ADD_TOPIC_DATA(this.data)
                .then((data) => {
                  this.FETCH_TOPIC_DATA();
                  this.$refs.form.reset();
                  this.$refs.form.resetValidation();
                  this.close();
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                       console.log(err)
                });
            }
          });
      }
    },
    close() {
      this.$emit("input", false);
    },
}
  watch: {
    dataRow(val) {
      this.data = { ...val };
    },
  },
```

Problem I am having is after adding a data, then if I try to add again by opening the dialog, the required field shows validation error, which is name here!
Image of that -->

[image: Validation Error]

Searched in stackoverflow. Found that should use this.$refs.form.reset(). Used that in save method without success. Also used this.$refs.form.resetValidation(), but don't work.
Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is you're assigning new value to dataRow when opening the dialog which triggers validation inside the dialog. You could also use lazy-validation prop which allows you to only manually trigger the validation.